# Move latest commit to a branch before the merge

Tags: git, branch

I merged a branch and pushed it to my GitHub page, but now I want to move that commit into a branch that has been already merged. This is how it looks like right now:

[image]

I'm trying to move the latest commit in master into the `open-process-list` branch before the point it was merged.

So right now it's like this (* is a commit):

```
*=====================*==*
 \   master          /
  \==*==*==*==*==X==/
      open-process-list
```

I want to move the latest commit where I placed the "X".

The reason I want to do this is because every single of my branches represents a feature. It should only get merged one time, once the feature is done. After I merged a new feature, I remembered I wanted to change one more thing, but had to commit it to master because the branch was already merged.

Is it possible, or is it too late to do that now?

Comment: @rkta It's only me, no other contributors.